# How to add multiple items to string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I know how to do it with cout:

```
cout << "string" << 'c' << 33;
```

But how to perform this so output is redirected to variable instead directly to standard out ?

```
const char* string << "string" << 'c' << 33; //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `std::stringstream` from C++ standard library.

It works like the following:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "string" << 'c' << 33;
std::string str = ss.str();
const char* str_ansi_c = str.c_str();
```

Keep in mind `str` still needs to be in the scope while you are using C-style `str_ansi_c`.

Comment: stringstream isn't a part of the STL.

Comment: @Pubby: No, it's part of the C++ standard library. A minor point of pedantry. But computers are nothing if not pedantic.

Comment: Should it not be `const char* str_ansi_c = str.c_str();`?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

main()
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "string" << 'c' << 33;

  std::string str = ss.str();
  std::cout << str;
}
```